# Got the following error when trying to install openssl package

Tags: 16.04, error-handling

I'm trying to install new package and got the following errors, how can I fix that?

```
# sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

here is the `df --si` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            238M     0  238M   0% /dev
tmpfs            52M  4.0M   48M   8% /run
/dev/vda1       5.2G  5.2G     0 100% /
tmpfs           256M     0  256M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           256M     0  256M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            52M     0   52M   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: sorry, added the output

Comment: thanks for answers! what minimum space is ok for OS?